# Best game loop architecture

Tags: architecture, game-loop

So I understand how a game loop works (listenInputs/updateData/redrawInterface) but what I'm struggling with is how am I supposed to equalize rendering? I initially thought I had to make the thread sleep for 16.67 ms (in order to get a 60fps output on the screen) but if a user has a low quality hardware it will slow the game down instead of the traditionnal "frame skip", so I figured out this solution was not valid.
So what I thought was the way to go was (in pseudo-java but langage doesn't really matter):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(...){
    int tick = Math.round((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / (1000.0 / 60));
    listenInputs();
    updateData();
    redrawInterface();
}
```

So now anything graphical such as displaying a looping animation can easily be done by printing the specific image of the whole animation for instance. 
Am I right? Or is there a better solution or a way to make this one run better?
But with this technique I will have to re-synchronize it every x ticks otherwise it will shift because 1000.0 / 60 is still not an exact value.

Comment: This looks like a question with [well-documented answers already available online](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) - do you need something that hasn't already been explained in sources like this?

Comment: I'll come back to you once I've read it, thanks you tho